# Why ldapsearch return nothing but slapcat does?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to understand how ldap work. I tried to list the olcAccess of ldap with this  command

```
$ ldapsearch -x -b 'cn=config' "objectclass=*" -s sub
# extended LDIF

#
# LDAPv3
# base <cn=config> with scope subtree
# filter: objectclass=*
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object

# numResponses: 1
```

I also tried with the admin user (`ldapsearch -x -W -D 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com' -s sub -b 'cn=config' 'objectclass=*'`). Same output as above.

But with `slapcat -b 'cn=config'`, I get everything.

Why ?

Comment: Are you sure that you execute `ldapsearsh` on a LDAP server with the same DB you use in `slapcat`? Just to ensure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is not posible to do this with simple authentication.

You have to use the EXTERNAL mechanism for operations against the config DIT of the local ldap server:

```
sudo ldapsearch -LLLY EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config
```